# summary tasks in Microsoft project 2010

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

if i add a summary task in microsft project planning how do i make 3/4/5..... tasks below under it. i have created summary tasks but the tasks beneath them are not consistent. for example

```
week 5(summary task)
   admin view prototype with flows
final domain class diagrams


Week 6(summary task)   
 Studying dreamweaver and how to implement it.  
 Editing and finalizing ppt and handouts  
 Sequence Diagrams  Creating tables  
 studying and implemeting CakePHP  
 Creating Risk Analysis Loading    Week 7(summary task)
  Mock Presentation 
     week 7 
       presentation to client 
       Continuation of making tables
```

its coming somewhat like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to get used to using the Indent and Outdent functions.

Referring to the example above:

1. It looks like "final domain class diagrams" should belong to "week 5". If so, select that task and press the Indent button at the top of the window
2. It looks like "week 7" should be a top level task and not a subordinate of "Mock Presentation". If so, select the "week 7" task and press the Outdent button at the top of the window until the task can be outdented no further. The subordinate tasks of "Week 7" should be automatically outdented as they "follow" their summary task

When entering tasks into Project, it automatically indents the current task to match the level of the previous task. Just keep an eye on them as you enter them and ensure each task is indented to the correct level as you input. You can always go back in later and fixup the indenting if you made a mistake.